# Running Xcode Tests on an Offline System

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode seems to be designed to be connected to the Internet and Apple developer server. Developing on an offline system requires extra steps, but most of these can be done via the Xcode UI and importing provisioning profiles.

When trying to run Tests on Xcode v9.2 on an offline system, there is an error during compilation stating:

> Signing with "YourAppTests" requires a development team

Inspecting the Tests targets confirms this error. However, pressing the "Add Account..." button results in a prompt to sign in with your Apple ID, which isn't possible with an offline system.

How can Tests and UITests be run via Xcode on an offline system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can be resolved by editing the `project.pbxproj` file directly.

1. Find your Team ID on the Apple Developer website on the Membership page
2. Open `project.pbxproj` in an external editor
3. Search for `buildSettings` that match the Release and Debug configurations for your Tests and UITests targets
4. At the line `DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = "";`, add your Team ID between the quotation marks

You should now be able to build your Tests on XCode on an offline system.